# Kubernetes starts giving errors after few hours of uptime

Tags: kubernetes, coreos

I have installed K8S on OpenStack following [this guide](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/coreos_multinode_cluster.md).

The installation went fine and I was able to run pods but after some time my applications stops working. I can still create pods but request won't reach the services from outside the cluster and also from within the pods. Basically, something in networking gets messed up. The **iptables -L -vnt nat** still shows the proper configuration but things won't work.

To make it working, I have to rebuild cluster, removing all services and replication controllers doesn't work.

I tried to look into the logs. Below is the journal for kube-proxy:

```
Dec 20 02:12:18 minion01.novalocal systemd[1]: Started Kubernetes Proxy.
    Dec 20 02:15:52 minion01.novalocal kube-proxy[1030]: I1220 02:15:52.269784    1030 proxier.go:487] Opened iptables from-containers public port for service "default/opensips:sipt" on TCP port 5060
    Dec 20 02:15:52 minion01.novalocal kube-proxy[1030]: I1220 02:15:52.278952    1030 proxier.go:498] Opened iptables from-host public port for service "default/opensips:sipt" on TCP port 5060
    Dec 20 03:05:11 minion01.novalocal kube-proxy[1030]: W1220 03:05:11.806927    1030 api.go:224] Got error status on WatchEndpoints channel: &{TypeMeta:{Kind: APIVersion:} ListMeta:{SelfLink: ResourceVersion:} Status:Failure Message:401: The event in requested index is outdated and cleared (the requested history has been cleared [1433/544]) [2432] Reason: Details:<nil> Code:0}
    Dec 20 03:06:08 minion01.novalocal kube-proxy[1030]: W1220 03:06:08.177225    1030 api.go:153] Got error status on WatchServices channel: &{TypeMeta:{Kind: APIVersion:} ListMeta:{SelfLink: ResourceVersion:} Status:Failure Message:401: The event in requested index is outdated and cleared (the requested history has been cleared [1476/207]) [2475] Reason: Details:<nil> Code:0}
..
..
..
Dec 20 16:01:23 minion01.novalocal kube-proxy[1030]: E1220 16:01:23.448570    1030 proxier.go:161] Failed to ensure iptables: error creating chain "KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER": fork/exec /usr/sbin/iptables: too many open files:
Dec 20 16:01:23 minion01.novalocal kube-proxy[1030]: W1220 16:01:23.448749    1030 iptables.go:203] Error checking iptables version, assuming version at least 1.4.11: %vfork/exec /usr/sbin/iptables: too many open files
Dec 20 16:01:23 minion01.novalocal kube-proxy[1030]: E1220 16:01:23.448868    1030 proxier.go:409] Failed to install iptables KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER rule for service "default/kubernetes:"
Dec 20 16:01:23 minion01.novalocal kube-proxy[1030]: E1220 16:01:23.448906    1030 proxier.go:176] Failed to ensure portal for "default/kubernetes:": error checking rule: fork/exec /usr/sbin/iptables: too many open files:
Dec 20 16:01:23 minion01.novalocal kube-proxy[1030]: W1220 16:01:23.449006    1030 iptables.go:203] Error checking iptables version, assuming version at least 1.4.11: %vfork/exec /usr/sbin/iptables: too many open files
Dec 20 16:01:23 minion01.novalocal kube-proxy[1030]: E1220 16:01:23.449133    1030 proxier.go:409] Failed to install iptables KUBE-PORTALS-CONTAINER rule for service "default/repo-client:"
```

I found few posts relating to "failed to install iptables" but they don't seem to be relevant as initially everything works but after few hours it gets messed up.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Kubernetes is this?  A long time ago (~1.0.4) we had a bug in the kube-proxy where it leaked sockets/file-descriptors.

If you aren't running a 1.1.3 binary, consider upgrading.

Also, you should be able to use `lsof` to figure out who has all of the files open.

Comment: I am not sure how to check version, but I think it is 1.1.2, which I see in master.yaml of setup. Also, _kubectl version_ gives `Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"0", GitVersion:"v1.0.6"} 
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"0", GitVersion:"v1.0.3"} `

Comment: ya you are using old versions so you should upgrade.